# "this" is equal to window instead of my wrapper-div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why are console.log(this) = window instead of the "wrapper"-div? I use a arrow function because that would bind this to the div?

```
const slider = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
let isDown = false;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  console.log(this);
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <title>Drag and drop</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="item item1">1</div>
     <div class="item item2">2</div>
     <div class="item item3">3</div>
     <div class="item item4">4</div>
     <div class="item item5">5</div>
   </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"I use a arrow function because that would bind this to the div?"* It's exactly the opposite. Related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I use a arrow function because that would bind this to the div?

No, arrow functions close over the `this` where they're defined, and `this` isn't the div where you're creating that arrow function. Moreover, arrow functions don't have a `this` of their own (because they close over it), so the event mechanism can't call it with the correct `this` as it normally would.

Use a normal function instead, or use `slider` instead of `this`.

Using a normal function:

```
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { // ***
  console.log(this);
  isDown = true;
  this.classList.add('active');
});
```

Using `slider` (just for completeness; you already were):

```
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
});
```